# how to display content above the MENU_LOCAL_TASK tabs in drupal

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6

so I have a bunch of drupal MENU_LOCAL_TASK menu items that gets displayed as tabs...

is there a way that I can position content above this tab?

I'm using drupal 6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a region in your page.tpl.php above where the $tabs variable is output.

Ex:
1. Edit your $THEME.info file to add a region called "above_tabs"
2. Edit your page.tpl.php file to  where you want content to appear.

Flush cache and you should now have a region to which you can assign blocks of content.